# Blazor WASM redirect to page not found after login from OIDC

Tags: openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

I have a Blazor WASM app, and i am using IDS(Identity Server) for authorization.

After the successful login from IDS i get redirected back to app with the error message "Sorry, there's nothing at this address."
[image]

I have setup @attribute [Authorize] on a Counter page for testing but same happens if i use it on Home page.

Basiclly this is the message from Router.NotFound component

There has been a fix for this here [WASM Redirect not working](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/497)

I have tried this but still redirect goes to NotFound

This is my redirect uri setting
"RedirectUri": "https://localhost:7095/signin-oidc"

Redirect uri and grant types is setup on both client and server.

**Edit:**

I got my answer, i was using wrong redirect url.

Correct one:
"RedirectUri": "https://localhost:7095/authentication/login-callback"

I was using
"RedirectUri": "https://localhost:7095/signin-oidc"

Comment: Maybe try redirect uri to be  https://localhost:7095/

Comment: Redirect to https://localhost:7095/ just keeps on repeating the auth process.

Comment: where do you handle the callback from auth ?

Comment: @J.Memisevic
I am following this article from MS docs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio 
Correct me if i am wrong that we dont need to create a page for /signin-oidc.
Sorry I am new to this an example or related article would be helpful.